# How to detect incomplete multibyte character in WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, utf-8, multibyte

I'm using [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert an UTF-8 encoded stream to wide characters. When there is an incomplete character and the end of conversion buffer, this function replaces it with '?' sign.
What checks/settings should I implement to detect incomplete characters for them to be prepended to the next buffer?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [Wikipedia entry on UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), there's a handy table that shows the possible types of multibyte configurations. The key thing with UTF8 is that initial bytes all follow one set of bit patterns, while follow bytes all follow another bit pattern. Notably all the follow bytes have the bit pattern 10xxxxxx.

It seems you can find a suitable break point by scanning backwards from the end of the string until you find a byte that does not match 10xxxxxx; if that byte is 0xxxxxxx, then end the string after that byte (since it's a single-byte sequence), otherwise end the string at/before it (since its the start of a multi-byte sequence), and add the byte(s) after it to the start of the next string.

Answer (score 0):

[how they do it in Python](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/unicodeobject.c)
Unfortunately that seems to be wrong as they only detect leading byte in a single position, while it can be a part of three or four byte long character and therefore harder to locate :(

Moreover that method works only for a few selected encodings, [says documentation on IsDBCSLeadByteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd318667.aspx). And [this article explains why](http://www.siao2.com/2007/04/19/2190207.aspx), but doesn't make life any easier.